# Does tar.gz do effective file compression of large files?

Tags: tar, compression, gzip

I wanted to compress a ~29GB file significantly, and used the `tar` command in the terminal like this :

```
 tar cvzf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

and it compressed it to ~26GB, so I looked up maximum compression on the internet and did this :

```
 export GZIP=-9
 env GZIP=-9 tar cvzf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

but still the tar.gz file size is showing to be around ~26GB in properties. I thought this time it would be compressed to ~10GB, say. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the file *should* be 10 Gb after compression? (Perhaps GZIP=-9 found no additional compressible bits)

Comment: I am not saying I know it can be compressed to ~10GB, I only expected a heavy amount of compression. My question is can it be better? Say I want it to be compressed to ~10GB or less? I have very little space left in my hdd.

Comment: The amount of compression you can achieve depends heavily on the type of data that you compress. You have said nothing about the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would never use the default builtin compression ratio and if I know that the unpacking machine is able to give a few hundred MB of RAM, I would use `xz` instead of `gzip`.

So my advise is do pipe the uncompressed  `tar` output through `xz -9`.

This needs significantly more CPU time while compressing but the CPU time for unpacking t needs only a bit more than you need with `gzip`. For text files, this results in 25-30% better compression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

You may want to try some of the other compression formats that tar offers.  On my Linux box, GNU tar offers this variety.  That said, if `gzip -9` is only achieving 29GB->26GB, it's quite unlikely that another compression format will achieve the desired 29GB->10GB you're seeking.

```
$ tar --help|grep -A16 Compression
 Compression options:

  -a, --auto-compress        use archive suffix to determine the compression
                             program
  -I, --use-compress-program=PROG
                             filter through PROG (must accept -d)
  -j, --bzip2                filter the archive through bzip2
  -J, --xz                   filter the archive through xz
      --lzip                 filter the archive through lzip
      --lzma                 filter the archive through lzma
      --lzop
      --no-auto-compress     do not use archive suffix to determine the
                             compression program
  -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip   filter the archive through gzip
  -Z, --compress, --uncompress   filter the archive through compress

 Local file selection:
$
```